# Highcharts chart didn't redraw after vue data changed

Tags: javascript, vue.js, highcharts

I grab the example from: https://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-stacked

Also referring some of the code from: [How to use Vue bound data in Highcharts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48707827/how-to-use-vue-bound-data-in-highcharts)

I build a sample as bellow:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.13/vue.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highcharts/7.1.1/highcharts.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>      
        <div id="app">
           <div id="container">
        </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
<script>
    new Vue({
        el: "#app",
        data: {
            chart: undefined,
            config: {
                chart: {
                    type: 'column'
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Stacked column chart'
                },
                xAxis: {
                    categories: ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears', 'Grapes', 'Bananas']
                },
                yAxis: {
                    min: 0,
                    title: {
                        text: 'Total fruit consumption'
                    },
                    stackLabels: {
                        enabled: true,
                        style: {
                            fontWeight: 'bold',
                            color: ( // theme
                                Highcharts.defaultOptions.title.style &&
                                Highcharts.defaultOptions.title.style.color
                            ) || 'gray'
                        }
                    }
                },
                legend: {
                    align: 'right',
                    x: -30,
                    verticalAlign: 'top',
                    y: 25,
                    floating: true,
                    backgroundColor:
                        Highcharts.defaultOptions.legend.backgroundColor || 'white',
                    borderColor: '#CCC',
                    borderWidth: 1,
                    shadow: false
                },
                tooltip: {
                    headerFormat: '<b>{point.x}</b><br/>',
                    pointFormat: '{series.name}: {point.y}<br/>Total: {point.stackTotal}'
                },
                plotOptions: {
                    column: {
                        stacking: 'normal',
                        dataLabels: {
                            enabled: true
                        }
                    }
                },
                series: [{
                    name: 'John',
                    data: [3, 3, 4, 8, 2]
                }, {
                    name: 'Jane',
                    data: [3, 2, 3, 2, 1]
                }, {
                    name: 'Joe',
                    data: [3, 4, 4, 3, 5]
                }]
            },
        },
        mounted() {
            this.render();
            // simulation of some data changing after some time
            setTimeout(() => {
                this.config.series = [{
                    name: 'John',
                    data: [53, 23, 24, 27, 32]
                }, {
                    name: 'Jane',
                    data: [23, 22, 23, 32, 31]
                }, {
                    name: 'Joe',
                    data: [33, 24, 24, 32, 35]
                }]
                console.log('updated')


            }, 3000)
        },
        watch: {
            config() {
                this.render();
            },
        },
        methods: {
            render() {              
                this.chart = Highcharts.chart('container', this.config)
            }
        }
    })

</script>
```

But I don't know why the chart wouldn't redraw after config.series updated ( with higher value of each category).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your `config` watcher only watch the change of `config` not its nested properties so `this.config.series = [...]` won't trigger your watcher.

First solution, use `deep` option:

```js
watch: {
  config: {
    handler() {
      this.render()
    },
    deep: true
  }
}
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/q4mfx7v6/)

Second solution, use spread syntax to assign the whole object:

```js
this.config = {
  ...this.config,
  series: [{ /* */ }]
}
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/1yw0c4md/)

Comment: Works now! Thanks! Now only Vue warn: "You may have an infinite update loop in watcher with expression "config"  , not sure what it mean, but it's warn, not error, highcharts is still work

Comment: I found the same warning in the first solution too. I think Vue can detect you are using `this.config` inside config watcher call stack, which if you update the config value it can be cause an infinite update loop.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution for you:

1. Destruct the config object in render method to lose a reference:

   ```
   render() {              
       this.chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {...this.config});
   }
   ```
2. Change your config watcher to deep (that way watcher will react when you are changing property that belongs to the object e.g. `this.config.series = [...]`):

   ```
   config: {
       deep: true,
       handler() {
           this.render();
       }
   }
   ```