# Vue3 composition api accessing component method from watch handler

Tags: javascript, vuejs3

I have a single file component in vue3 with the following relevant snippets. Part of this component is a VueHighCharts component that I need to force to re-render after the data updates.

I cannot understand how to run a component method on when the a watch handler runs. The property watch is working fine, but I cannot run the `forceRerender()` method of the component.

Can you help me from pulling more of my hair out? When the `series` property is updated with new data, the graph should redraw itself.

```js
export default {
  name: "ExampleComponent",
  components: {
    VueHighcharts,
    Widget,
  },
  props: {
      series: {
          type: Array,
          default: () => [],
      },
  },
  setup(props, context) {
    const showChart = true

    watch(() => props.series, (currentValue, oldValue) => {
       console.log("Series changed ", currentValue, oldValue)
       this.forceRerender()
    })

    return { showChart }
  },
  methods: {
    forceRerender() {
      this.showChart = false
      this.$nextTick(() => {
        this.showChart = true
      })
    }
  },
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59695876/highcharts-chart-didnt-redraw-after-vue-data-changed

This may be helpfull.

Comment: is `forceRerender` not getting called, or is it called and doing the update? AFAICT, `this.forceRerender()` will run if you're getting the console log

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few problems I see.

- You are mixing Composition API and Options API.
- Your `showChart` is not reactive.

A full Composition API example:

```js
import { ref, watch, nextTick } from "vue";

function useChart(props) {
    const showChart = ref(true);

    const forceRerender = () => {
        showChart.value = false;
        nextTick(() => {
            showChart.value = true;
        });
    };

    watch(() => props.series, (seriesNew, seriesOld) => {
        console.log("Series changed ", seriesNew, seriesOld);
        forceRerender();
    });

    return {
        showChart
    };
}

export default {
    props: {
        series: {
            type: Array,
            default: () => []
        }
    },

    setup(props) {
        return {
            ...useChart(props)
        };
    }
}
```

Since I don't know the full context here and don't see how VueHighCharts is used inside the template, just a wild guess:

If `series` is passed to VueHighCharts and what you want to redraw depends on `series` AND if `showChart` is just being used to hide/show VueHighCharts then hiding/showing it is not really the problem. You might be breaking the reactivity chain of `series` somewhere in your code.

Answer (score 1):

I think this problem reason is this keyword. try this code:

```
watch(() => props.series, function propChangeHandler(currentValue, oldValue) {
       console.log("Series changed ", currentValue, oldValue)
       this.forceRerender()
}.bind(this))
```

Comment: Thank @ahmadkzx - but in the `setup()` of a composition api component, this is `undefined` which was really the problem I was trying to navigate. Sorry for not being clearer.